# Google Charts in a Google Apps Scripts HTML App

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I’m trying to get a Google Chart to work in Apps Script.  The chart works in a fiddle, seen at the following link:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/441cvw9o/2/)

But only part of it works in Google Apps Script.

The `doGet()` code is:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

The original code is from another stack overflow post shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971275/switching-horizontal-axes-with-the-legend-in-google-charts)

Comment: So, part of it is working, and part of it is not working?  What part is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the third filter is not working to Google Apps Script.

1 filter - Population (working)
2 filter - Characteristic (working)
3 filter - Filter (dos not work)..

Comment: sorry, this wasn't an answer...only comment

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined    $('#subc').change(function () {

Comment: this should be jquery statement... not sure

Comment: please see the stackoverflow faq for "how to ask a question". also please use a single comment in the future.